# Spring Boot 3.1.1 ignores some jpa hibernate properties in application.properties but uses them when in hibernate.properties?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm a little bit confused.

Using Spring Boot 3.1.1 where I have usual Rest+Service+Repo setup.

I wanted to insert some entities in BATCH mode, but whatever I tried in application.properties, JPA would not use batching.

It respects some hibernate properties, like the dialect etc., but completely ignores others like batch_size or even generate_statistics...

Here's my application.properties:

```
app.datasource.url=${DS_URL}
app.datasource.username=${DS_USERNAME}
app.datasource.password=${DS_PASSWORD}
app.datasource.driver-class-name=${DS_DRIVER}
app.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=${DS_MIN_IDLE:1}
app.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=${DS_MAX_SIZE:20}
app.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=10000
app.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=500000
app.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=900000
app.datasource.hikari.pool-name=APP-pool

init.asyncCorePoolSize=0
init.asyncMaxPoolSize=5
init.asyncQueueCapacity=5
server.address=${SERVER_ADDRESS:0.0.0.0}
server.port=${SERVER_PORT:8080}
init.packageNumber=${PACKAGE_NUMBER:1.0.0}

###### HERE IT GETS INTERESTING ######

# These props work!
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=${HIBERNATE_DIALECT}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

#These props are completely ignored!
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=${MAX_FILE_SIZE:300MB}
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=${MAX_REQU_SIZE:300MB}

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
# This is ignored as well
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

No statistics are generated, no batching is done,
but when I move these properties into a
hibernate.properties file, like

```
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

then everything works as expected.

Anybody have a clue what's wrong?
Using newest IntelliJ to run my app.

Comment: Did it work with other spring boot version? The hibernate.* props you can treat as "hibernate global". Not sure how spring maps the spring.* Props to entity manager...

Comment: Well I actually doubt the other `hibernate` properties are set as well as some are the already set defaults or can be set through other means. Judging by your configuration you have multiple datasources (at least you changed from the default configuration) which makes me wonder do you have your own `@Bean` which creates the `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`? The fact that you already have different named properties means you don't really have the usual setup as you claim in your question.